# AWS-CDK: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Parameters')

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm using aws cdk 2.132.1 to instrument a simple Lambda application.

I have one stack named `AllStack.ts` that's the parent stack of all other stacks (DynamoDB, SNS, SQS, StepFunction, etc.) which looks like below:

```
import * as cfn_inc from 'aws-cdk-lib/cloudformation-include';
import {CfnStateMachine} from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-stepfunctions';
import {Duration} from 'aws-cdk-lib';

interface AllStackProps {
    readonly env: DeploymentEnvironment;
    readonly lambdaFunction: IFunction;
}

export class AllStack extends DeploymentStack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, readonly props: AllStackProps) {
        super(scope, id, {
            env: props.env,
            softwareType: SoftwareType.INFRASTRUCTURE,
        });

        const cfnInclude = new cfn_inc.CfnInclude(this, 'Template', {
            templateFile: 'templates/root.yaml',
            // loadNestedStacks: {
            //   StepFunctionStack: {
            //     templateFile: 'templates/step_function.yaml',
            //     preserveLogicalIds: true,
            //     parameters: { 'Domain': props.env }
            //   },
            // },
            // parameters: {
            //     'Domain': props.env
            // }
        });
    }
}
```

It could build fine with `loadNestedStacks` part commented out, but when I uncommented these lines out, it failed to build with errors like this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Parameters')
    at CfnInclude.createNestedStack (ROOT_TO_MY_WORK_DIR/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/cloudformation-include/lib/cfn-include.js:1:15080)
    at CfnInclude.getOrCreateResource (ROOT_TO_MY_WORK_DIR/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/cloudformation-include/lib/cfn-include.js:1:13018)
    at CfnInclude.loadNestedStack (ROOT_TO_MY_WORK_DIR/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/cloudformation-include/lib/cfn-include.js:1:5353)
    at new AllStack (ROOT_TO_MY_WORK_DIR/dist/lib/allStack.js:26:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (ROOT_TO_MY_WORK_DIR/dist/lib/app.js:41:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
```

Here's what my whole folder looks like:

```
-FunServiceCDK
--lib
---allStack.ts
---app.ts
--templates
---root.yaml
---step_function.yaml
```

Here's what my `root.yaml` looks like:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Parameters:
  Domain:
    Type: String

Resources:
  StepFunctionStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
```

Here's what my `step_function.yaml` looks like:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Parameters:
  Domain:
    Type: String

Resources:
  ComputationStepFunction:
    Type: AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine
```

Looking at the CDK [CfnInclude doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/java/software/amazon/awscdk/cloudformation/include/CfnInclude.Builder.html), `parameters` is an optional field, and I've supplied this field in both .ts file and .yaml file, somehow it's still not working, could someone help in this case!

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack` is a supported type for a CloudFormation Parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Good call, I've updated it and retried, still faced with the same error.

Comment: Might be because your `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack` resource doesn't have all required properties defined. Try adding a template URL placeholder.

Comment: Yep, you nailed it, please feel free to post this as an answer and I'll comment with my changes that make it fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your root CloudFormation template, the `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack` does not have its required fields set. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudformation-stack.html), these are `StackName` and one of `TemplateBody`, `TemplateURL`.

You can either specify an no-op template body or a placeholder template URL. CDK will replace it with the stack that you specify.

From the CDK [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.cloudformation_include-readme.html):

> the TemplateURL property of the nested stack resource will be modified to point to that asset.

Comment: Yep, after I added `Properties: Parameters: id: 3` under my `Resources:
  StepFunctionStack: ` in `root.yaml` file, build worked, many thanks!